# Unity TCP server freezing

Tags: unity-game-engine, tcp

I'm trying to get tcp server working in unity, and it's kinda working. My systems purpose is to read data from another program that sends me bytes and draws me a picture of that data. Main problem is that when I run it, it works for a while (random time) and then whole unity freezes and I need to kill it from the task manager.

```
void Start()
{
    Display1 = gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>();
    mymat = GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
    packetReady = false;
    tcpListenerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForIncommingRequests));
    tcpListenerThread.IsBackground = true;
    tcpListenerThread.Start();
    bytes = new byte[1024];
    tex = new Texture2D(800, 1280, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    firstTime = true;
    ArrayInit(3072060);
    packetLength = 3072060;
    myThread = new Thread(Draw);
    myThread.Start();
}

void Draw()
{
    if (Loader == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    else if (packetReady)
    {
        tex.LoadRawTextureData(Loader);
        tex.Apply();
        mymat.SetTexture("_EmissionMap", tex);
        Display1.material.mainTexture = tex;
        packetReady = false;
    }
}


void Update()
{
    Draw();
}


private void ListenForIncommingRequests()
{
   try
     {
         tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 35800);
         tcpListener.Start();

         while (true)
         {

            if (!tcpListener.Pending())
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

            Thread.Sleep(10);

            using (connectedTcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient())
            {

                using (NetworkStream stream = connectedTcpClient.GetStream())
                {
                    int length;
                    while ((length = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                    {
                        if (bytes == null)
                        {
                            return;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ParseData(bytes);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

         }

     }

     catch (SocketException socketException)
     {
         Debug.Log("SocketException " + socketException.ToString());
     }
     finally
     {
         tcpListener.Stop();
     }
}
```

I have no idea what is causing this, I've tried to solve the problem but nothing seems to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: `while (true)` probably whats causing the problem.

Comment: any suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: You could use a coroutine.

Comment: @Hristo He's is using the `while` loop in another Thread and that is fine. Since this is a network code, coroutine wouldn't be useful here. The code in the question is not complete and the problem is likely from one of the functions missing from the code.

Comment: @programmer I can post the rest of the code here if you can help?

Comment: I don't have to agree to help you for you to post your code. Posting the complete code is what you're supposed to do so that any SO user can help you. If were you I would use `Debug.Log` to see which function or where the freezing is coming from. You can determine that by checking the last place  `Debug.Log` is called